# How to obtain absolute img src url with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get all the absolute urls of a website's images to display them, but I need the absolute url of a `$('img')`.

I tried:

```
$('img').attr('src')
```

but it only returned relative urls of a single one, I am using map to solve the problem of multiple images but still. How do I get the absolute url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.prop` instead of `.attr`. This accesses the dynamic property, which is after canonicalization, rather than the static DOM attribute.

```js
alert($('img').prop('src'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="placeholder.jpg"/>
```

See [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Why should I use prop() over src?

Comment: @baao Either way works, it's mostly a style choice. I prefer to stick with jQuery functions when they're available.

Answer (score 1):

This should give the absolute url for the first picture, of course you can loop through all of them:

```
$('img')[0].src
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i<$('img').length;i++) {
alert($('img')[i].src)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg"/>
<img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/140.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Your answer is not bad but i needed to get absolutes from relatives in you example you are using absolute urls i mean what should i do for a src='../whatever.jpg' without going through string concatenation etc. Thnx for taking the time anyway

Comment: Don't mind, but you will get absolute urls with src, no matter what the link is

Comment: oh then thanks a lot for your answer. I should have tried it in the console.